# snprintf crashing on OSX

Tags: c++, macos, haxe, stdio

This is a quite complicated post. I have a simple app made in Haxe. This app is being converted to C++ by hxcpp, which is an automated tool used to compile and deploy the app on different systems by transcompiling the Haxe code to C++.

This same app, when compiled for Windows or Linux works fine. 
When compiled for OSX it throws an error from inside a system library.

There's a long [thread about it on GitHub](https://github.com/jcward/vscode-hxcpp-debug/issues/25).

The summary is that for some reason that I cannot understand, the code that serializes a structure to a string (it's a recursive function) is making the snprintf() throw an exception with no apparent reason.

The stack trace is the following:

```
MBP-di-Valerio:test-snow-empty tanis$ lldb bin/mac64/snow_empty.app/Contents/MacOS/snow_empty
(lldb) target create "bin/mac64/snow_empty.app/Contents/MacOS/snow_empty"
Current executable set to 'bin/mac64/snow_empty.app/Contents/MacOS/snow_empty' (x86_64).
(lldb) run
Process 9216 launched: '/Users/tanis/Documents/test-snow-empty/bin/mac64/snow_empty.app/Contents/MacOS/snow_empty' (x86_64)
Debugger:Starting App side debugger support.
Debugger:Connected to debugging server at localhost:6972.
Process 9216 stopped
* thread #2: tid = 0xee65, 0x00007fff96d94d6d libsystem_c.dylib`_vsnprintf + 20, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x102100f68)
    frame #0: 0x00007fff96d94d6d libsystem_c.dylib`_vsnprintf + 20
libsystem_c.dylib`_vsnprintf:
->  0x7fff96d94d6d <+20>: movq   %r9, -0x1e8(%rbp)
    0x7fff96d94d74 <+27>: movq   %r8, %r15
    0x7fff96d94d77 <+30>: movq   %rcx, %rbx
    0x7fff96d94d7a <+33>: movq   %rdx, %r14
(lldb) bt
warning: could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.
* thread #2: tid = 0xee65, 0x00007fff96d94d6d libsystem_c.dylib`_vsnprintf + 20, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x102100f68)
  * frame #0: 0x00007fff96d94d6d libsystem_c.dylib`_vsnprintf + 20
    frame #1: 0x00007fff96d9500c libsystem_c.dylib`vsnprintf_l + 41
    frame #2: 0x00007fff96d853b2 libsystem_c.dylib`snprintf + 188
    frame #3: 0x000000010041da73 snow_empty`String::String(this=0x00000001021014c0, inRHS=0x0000000100d3710c) + 83 at String.cpp:311
    frame #4: 0x000000010041dbcd snow_empty`String::String(this=0x00000001021014c0, inRHS=0x0000000100d3710c) + 29 at String.cpp:309
    frame #5: 0x0000000100417aa3 snow_empty`hx::IntData::toString(this=0x0000000100d37104) + 35 at Dynamic.cpp:55
    frame #6: 0x000000010036b779 snow_empty`Std_obj::string(s=Dynamic @ 0x00000001021014b8) + 361 at Std.cpp:67
    frame #7: 0x000000010036a0fb snow_empty`StringBuf_obj::add(this=0x0000000100e40a18, x=Dynamic @ 0x0000000102101690) + 315 at StringBuf.cpp:44
    frame #8: 0x00000001002ac50a snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serializeString(this=0x0000000100e409ec, s=(length = 20, __s = "snow%2Fapi%2FLibs.hx")) + 1530 at Serializer.cpp:123
    frame #9: 0x00000001002ae8a9 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x0000000102104958) + 4409 at Serializer.cpp:300
    frame #10: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x0000000102107128) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #11: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x00000001021098f8) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #12: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x000000010210c0c8) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #13: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x000000010210e898) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #14: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x0000000102111068) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #15: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x0000000102113838) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #16: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x0000000102116008) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #17: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x00000001021187d8) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #18: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x000000010211afa8) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #19: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x000000010211d778) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #20: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x000000010211ff48) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #21: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x0000000102122718) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #22: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x0000000102124ee8) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #23: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x00000001021276b8) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #24: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x0000000102129e88) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #25: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x000000010212c658) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #26: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x000000010212ee28) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #27: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x00000001021315f8) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #28: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x0000000102133dc8) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #29: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x0000000102136598) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #30: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x0000000102138d68) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #31: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x000000010213b538) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #32: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x000000010213dd08) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #33: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x00000001021404d8) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #34: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x0000000102142ca8) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #35: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x0000000102145478) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #36: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x0000000102147c48) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #37: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x000000010214a418) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #38: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x000000010214cbe8) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #39: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x000000010214f3b8) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #40: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x0000000102151b88) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #41: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x0000000102154358) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #42: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x0000000102156b28) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #43: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x00000001021592f8) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #44: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x000000010215bac8) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #45: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x000000010215e298) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #46: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x0000000102160a68) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #47: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x0000000102163238) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #48: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x0000000102165a08) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #49: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x00000001021681d8) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #50: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x000000010216a9a8) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #51: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x000000010216d178) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #52: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x000000010216f948) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #53: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x0000000102172118) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #54: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x00000001021748e8) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #55: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x00000001021770b8) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #56: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x0000000102179888) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #57: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x000000010217c058) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #58: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x000000010217e828) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #59: 0x00000001002b5ef0 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::serialize(this=0x0000000100e409ec, v=Dynamic @ 0x0000000102180710) + 34688 at Serializer.cpp:796
    frame #60: 0x00000001002b6747 snow_empty`haxe::Serializer_obj::run(v=Dynamic @ 0x0000000102180980) + 423 at Serializer.cpp:842
    frame #61: 0x00000001002e4f30 snow_empty`debugger::HaxeProtocol_obj::writeDynamic(output=(mPtr = 0x0000000100e36cd0), value=Dynamic @ 0x0000000102180a98) + 304 at HaxeProtocol.cpp:237
    frame #62: 0x00000001002e56e4 snow_empty`debugger::HaxeProtocol_obj::writeMessage(output=(mPtr = 0x0000000100e36cd0), message=debugger::Message @ 0x0000000102180cb0) + 340 at HaxeProtocol.cpp:148
    frame #63: 0x00000001002df947 snow_empty`debugger::HaxeRemote_obj::writeThreadLoop(this=0x0000000100e36be8) + 759 at HaxeRemote.cpp:233
    frame #64: 0x00000001002e1a09 snow_empty`debugger::HaxeRemote_obj::__construct(this=0x0000000100e36fc8)::_Function_1_1::run() + 217 at HaxeRemote.cpp:75
    frame #65: 0x00000001002e18f3 snow_empty`debugger::HaxeRemote_obj::__construct(this=0x0000000100e36fc8)::_Function_1_1::__run() + 35 at HaxeRemote.cpp:79
    frame #66: 0x00000001003eb018 snow_empty`hxThreadFunc(inInfo=0x0000000100e36fdc) + 184 at Thread.cpp:255
    frame #67: 0x00007fff8dbac05a libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 131
    frame #68: 0x00007fff8dbabfd7 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 176
    frame #69: 0x00007fff8dba93ed libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13
(lldb)
```

I tried inspecting the variables as the function calling into snprintf() boils down to this:

```
typedef char buf[100];
snprintf(buf, 100, "%d", 12);
```

where `12` is just an int being passed to the function (it's the length of a string it's serializing)

Since snprintf on OSX uses vsnprintf internally I even ventured into rewriting that in my own code just to check what parameters were passed and if they were ok:

```
int String::snprintf(char *str,size_t count,const char *fmt,...)
{
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, fmt);
  (void) vsnprintf(str, count, fmt, ap);
  va_end(ap);
  return(strlen(str));
}
```

and in fact everything seems fine. But it still crashes in the inner `libsystem_c.dylib`_vsnprintf`.
I really cannot understand what's going on and why this is happening just on OSX and not on other systems.

[This is the original offending code](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/hxcpp/blob/master/src/String.cpp#L308). I'm open to any suggestion to try and narrow down this issue.

Comment: I think there is a memory access bug before calling this function and the stack or the memory heap is messed up. The assembly code that causes the access exception tries to load data from stack using the epb register which usually points to the stack frame of every function.

Comment: @ul90 I've been thinking about that as well. At first I thought it might be the stack size which is lower than on Windows or Linux, but even increasing it with ulimit -s didn't help. If it's something that's corrupting the stack, do you know if there's any tool that could help narrowing it down?

Comment: i don't think it's the stack size (this usually only the case if you have a recursive algorithm without correct break condition). I think the stack frame is messed up earlier. This is often caused by too small buffers (local variables) on the stack and then using old-style C string functions. It seems that the haxe-to-c++ compiler is using this old-style C things heavily, so i guess there is a bug in the haxe-to-c++ compiler. You can find this bug only by using a debugger and lots lots lots of time...

Comment: I was surprised that method is passing in an `int &` and what effect that will have on a C function.  I don't see why it's passing in a reference anyway.

Comment: @trojanfoe I tried removing the `&` but nothing changed. I have no idea why it's there but it looks like that's not what's breaking it. But that isn't the only function getting parameters as reference. So it might as well be some other function that is corrupting the stack before that one is being hit.

Comment: @ul90 do you have any reference docs about old style C string functions and stack corruption that I could look up, by any chance?

Comment: The most stack-access bugs come from local variables (mostly char arrays) in a functions that are written to by strcpy, strncpy, memcpy, memove, sprintf etc. (most functions from stdlib.h and string.h) If these buffers are too small (or the write accesses are to big), the memory following the variable is overwritten. In the case of local variables, the overwritten area contains other local variables and maybe the stack frame for the function and possible even the stack of the caller function, which consists of the last stack pointer, the function return address and the saved registers.

Comment: @trojanfoe: in fact, the `int&` is nonsense in this case, but the clang or gcc compiler is clever enough to remove this.

Comment: @ValerioSantinelli Not looking at the entire code, using reference variables with varargs functions is risky, if not undefined behavior.  https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/EXP58-CPP.+Do+not+pass+a+reference+or+nontrivially+copyable+type+to+va_start

Comment: Misleading title: It doesn't throw an exception, it crashes.

Comment: @gnasher729 changed the title

Comment: In practice, snprintf will crash when the output buffer is rubbish, or when the format string is rubbish, and with certain formats (like %s) when the parameter is rubbish. Because all printf variations use varargs, it would be possible that passing a 64 bit value where the format expects 32 bits might move parameters into the wrong places, so a %s might have a perfectly fine string parameter, but access the wrong bytes to read that string parameter.

Comment: Try what happens with a 32 bit version; if that works you have some problem where 32 bit / 64 bit were mixed up. For example using %d to print a "long" is just fine in 32 bit but might cause trouble in 64 bit. Then I'd check the source code as far as it is visible to you; and you can set breakpoints even if you don't have the source code.

Comment: The int& mentioned above could be a problem, because an int& is a pointer is 64 bit while %d expects 32 bit.

Comment: I tried enabling libgmalloc: `export DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib/libgmalloc.dylib` and passing the `-fstack-protector-all` flag to the compiler and now it prints the following lines when compiling: `GuardMalloc[haxelib-17514]: Allocations will be placed on 16 byte boundaries.` `GuardMalloc[haxelib-17514]:  - Some buffer overruns may not be noticed.`

Comment: I also increased that buffer size to 16k but I guess it's not just that function that might be corrupting the memory

Comment: @ul90 in pure theory snprintf should be safe from buffer overflows because at most it fills size-1 bytes of the receiving buffer. In my case the buffer has always a fixed size and the length passed is fixed as well and it doesn't look like those numbers in n the original code are wrong. I wonder if it could be of any help to use std::string in place of C strings manipulation.

Comment: @Valerio Santinelli: using std::string could help - but you would have to change the haxe compiler, i think this is not so easy. The snprintf is not the problem here, even if the parameter is interpreted as 64 bits (which would only print a wrong value into the string). It seems that the stack frame is messed up and the ebp register contains an invalid address. I guess the bug is before this single function.

Comment: @ul90 I tried converting the linked list that I'm trying to serialize to an array and the fact that the array isn't being recursively serialized unlike the list did make this work. It's definitely something that messes up the stack but I guess the real problem is one more step up. The serializer should probably use a different algorithm so that it doesn't recurse like it's doing now. The original writer suggested using variable stack instead of recursion. That's probably the best approach